# Cannot get final name for export 'Observable' of __barrel_optimize__

Tags: next.js, rxjs, sanity, barrel-import

I've started experiencing these issues after adding Sanity to my Next.js/Typescript app.

```
Cannot get final name for export 'Observable' of __barrel_optimize__?names=Observable,lastValueFrom!=!./node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm5/index.js
```

This is probably related to some issue with Next.js `optimizePackageImports` feature and the way the imports are done in the `@sanity/client` package.

Similar issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/55818

Is there any known workaround to solve this? Thanks :)

```
"@sanity/client": "^6.9.1",
"next-sanity": "^7.0.1",
```

---

***UPDATE***

Downgrading to `next-sanity: 3.1.9` temporarily solved the build issue for me.